# How to make a for loop in variables

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to know how to write for loop for the function below.

```
def row_column_number(data):
    
    rows, columns = data.shape
    
    print(f'Number of rows for the dataset are {rows}')
    print(f'Number of columns for the dataset are {columns}')
```

I tried this but this is not what I like

```
>> for dimensions in enumerate(data.shape):
>>     print(f'Number of {dimensions}')

Number of (0, 4803)
Number of (1, 24)
```

How can I write a for loop for the `{rows, columns}` variable above.

`Number of {for-loop variable} for the dataset are {for-loop value}`

Comment: The for loop uses a specific variable; you can't change its name each time through the loop. Also, you can't access the variable's name from the value; you can only access it from the variable, in which case you already know what the name is. What you want to do is use **strings** to store names for the dimensions. Variable names aren't storage. Variable names are there so that you can say which variable you mean when you write the code.

Comment: You said, "I want to know how to write for loop for the function below.". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Instead, make a separate **list of strings** for the names that you want to use, and then iterate in parallel - see the linked duplicate. I was going to try to write up an answer to explain the conceptual idea behind why we want to do it this way - but it's really straightforward once you have the idea, and it's hard to make a good Q&A out of it. The problem is, if anyone else actually is confused in the same way, it doesn't result in a question that makes sense to type into a search engine, and it definitely wouldn't find this post.